# Expo valid hosts

Tags: react-native, expo

I have built a react-native app using the new `create-react-native` which uses expo. I have opened port 19000 yet when I try to connect to `exp://mydomain.com:19000` in the app I get a network response timed out.

When I connect to `mydomain.com:19000` in chrome I get `{"error":"Error: ValidationError: \"host\" is not allowed"}` How do I configure external connections and valid hosts? Or is this not possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try opening port 19001 as well. That might help.

Comment: This is correct the answer made alsome find that my `packager-info.json` file had been changed all ports null after changing that I got it to work. Thankyou!